# How to create an Outlook Calendar API Compatible Date in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, outlook, calendar

I'm creating an event in the outlook calendar using the Microsoft graph API. I'm using retrofit for Retrofit for sending HTTP request.
For creating an event, I have an event model as :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

/**
 * The Class Event.
 */
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Event
{

   /** The id. */
   private String id;

   /** The subject. */
   private String subject;

   /** The start. */
   private DateTimeTimeZone start;

   /** The end. */
   private DateTimeTimeZone end;

   /**
    * Gets the id.
    *
    * @return the id
    */
   public String getId()
   {
      return id;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the id.
    *
    * @param id the new id
    */
   public void setId( String id )
   {
      this.id = id;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the subject.
    *
    * @return the subject
    */
   public String getSubject()
   {
      return subject;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the subject.
    *
    * @param subject the new subject
    */
   public void setSubject( String subject )
   {
      this.subject = subject;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the start.
    *
    * @return the start
    */
   public DateTimeTimeZone getStart()
   {
      return start;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the start.
    *
    * @param start the new start
    */
   public void setStart( DateTimeTimeZone start )
   {
      this.start = start;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the end.
    *
    * @return the end
    */
   public DateTimeTimeZone getEnd()
   {
      return end;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the end.
    *
    * @param end the new end
    */
   public void setEnd( DateTimeTimeZone end )
   {
      this.end = end;
   }
}
```

DateTimeZone Class

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

/**
 * The Class DateTimeTimeZone.
 */
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DateTimeTimeZone
{

   /** The date time. */
   private Date dateTime;

   /** The time zone. */
   private String timeZone;

   /**
    * Gets the date time.
    *
    * @return the date time
    */
   public Date getDateTime()
   {
      return dateTime;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the date time.
    *
    * @param dateTime the new date time
    */
   public void setDateTime( Date dateTime )
   {
      this.dateTime = dateTime;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the time zone.
    *
    * @return the time zone
    */
   public String getTimeZone()
   {
      return timeZone;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the time zone.
    *
    * @param timeZone the new time zone
    */
   public void setTimeZone( String timeZone )
   {
      this.timeZone = timeZone;
   }
}
```

For demo purpose I'm creating a hard coded Event object from the calling service like :

```
//Some Service.java
IOutlookSservice outlookService = OutlookServiceBuilder.getOutlookService( tokens.getAccessToken(), null );
               Event event = new Event ();
               event.setSubject( crm.getSubject() + " Created from API" );
               DateTimeTimeZone start = new DateTimeTimeZone();
               start.setDateTime( new Date() );
               start.setTimeZone( "Pacific Standard Time" );
               DateTimeTimeZone end = new DateTimeTimeZone();
               end.setDateTime( new Date() );
               end.setTimeZone( "Pacific Standard Time" );
               event.setStart( start );
               event.setEnd( end );

               int code = outlookService.createEvent( event ).execute().code();
               System.out.println( code );
```

This is how the request looks like :

```
{
    "id": null,
    "subject": "null Created from API",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": 1515414749993,
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": 1515414751989,
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    }
}
```

As I can see the **dateTime** field is somehow being converted to long milliseconds. How to stop that and rather have this as the date format **"2018-01-07T12:37:12.755Z"**

This is the error being received :

```
 {
   "error": {
     "code": "RequestBodyRead",
     "message": "Cannot convert the literal '1515413901387' to the expected type 'Edm.String'.",
     "innerError": {
       "request-id": "901a0d77-131c-4c81-9c02-972c62d05ae4",
       "date": "2018-01-08T12:19:19"
     }
   }
 }
```

Which part to change so that the date becomes compatible?

Answer (score 0):

You got the same (de)serialization of the date in the case of the GET? "dateTime":"2018-06-16T00:00:00.0000000"
If not you need to write a custom one

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue myself but i was able to fix it by using @JsonFormat for the date in the DateTimeTimeZone class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DateTimeTimeZone {
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private Date dateTime;
    private String timeZone;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " dateTime: " + dateTime.toString() + " timezone: " + timeZone;
    }

}
```

This should fix your problem as well